# confusion about calculating an AWS signature - uncertain what information is being asked for

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make an `AWS` signature for an HTTP Header, and this is my first time with this kind of system - I'm having a very hard time grasping what they're asking for.

Hunting for a few hours online, I found some various code snippets as well as the code on Amazon's own tutorials about the signature calculation;

for example, this one looks like it is intended to calculate the full signature from a given key;

### [github gist](https://gist.github.com/ciel/ee9e67328417c0664c900e88f8178545)

amazon offers their own code to generate a key

### [amazon code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet)

but I am still very confused. I have the amazon `AWS SECRET KEY` from my control panel, but I can't figure out what to plug in where.

The first code I linked has a `CalculateSignature` method that asks for an `HttpRequestMessage`, a `string[]` of 'signedHeaders', and the date.

I can't figure out what these want. What message am I supposed to put through? What does it mean by signed headers? Are the signed headers `host;range;x-amz-date`?

Can anyone assist with this? I have no idea what that `HttpRequestMessage` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is you make a signature from the current date and the whole request: URL, query parameters, headers and content.

The problem is some of these things can be represented in multiple ways, so you have to create *canonical* versions of them.  This is just a very specific representation that AWS can reproduce exactly on their side to verify the signature.

For example, the headers need to be in a specific format: sorted by key, no whitespace between key and value, separated by a semicolon.  If the request is made by an API or goes through a proxy, extra headers might be added along the way (e.g. `User-Agent`, `X-Forwarded-For`, etc.).  `signedHeaders` tells AWS which headers you included in the signature, so it can ignore the others.  You can use at minimum `host`, `x-amz-date` and `x-amz-content-sha256`.

The `AWS_SECRET_KEY` is used as the input to `getSignatureKey`.  In the first example, it's `_awsSecretKey`.

The `HttpRequestMessage` is simply the HTTP request you want to send to AWS.  The most simple example is a GET request to S3 to retrieve a file, but it could be any API call to an AWS service.  You need to initialize the `HttpRequestMessage` with the correct method (GET/POST/etc), path (the API endpoint), query parameters and/or body.  Once you have the signature from  `GetSignature`, you need to include it in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. So I need to figure out the URL for a Get Request to the Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: If you click on a file in the AWS S3 Console, the URL will show up in the Properties tab as "Link".  It's just the endpoint, bucket, and key all concatenated together.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I can do this, now.